# Sphinx variables

Tags: sphinx

I have a lot of filenames in my Sphinx config with name like `/home/ubuntu/sites/sitename.dev/data/sphinx/searchd.pid` with same path prefix.

Can I separate path `/home/ubuntu/sites/sitename.dev/data/sphinx/` from that filename into variable to use it like `$path/searchd.pid`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its a little known feature, but the config file can actully be a script - such as PHP, perl or even plain old bash. Just uses a classic shebang line - if the first line begins with #! that intpreter is used to execute the script, and the output used as the conf file.

Example for PHP..

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php 
  $path = "/home/ubuntu/sites/sitename.dev/";
?>

searchd {
     pid_file = <?php echo $path; ?>/searchd.pid
}
```

As a side note why are you having multiple pid files? Surely its best to have one single pid file - ie one single instance of searchd. A single instance can serve many indexes. 
You can use this scripting capablity, to keep seperate 'files' for each index (for easy of use) - which the script consolidates into one file for use.

Comment: Thank you, it works. BTW pid file is just an example. Other files are indexes/logs with the same directory.